# How to set UIButton's isSelected property inside another closure in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton

After user accepts setting notification on AlertController, I have to set UIButton inside the TableViewCell selected if adding the notification request finishes succesfully. But it doesn't respond to that even though the code reaches there. I think the problem is, Handler Event's closure is different from the main function's closure and because of that it doesn't get UIButton object correctly inside handler event closure. How can i tackle this issue? Here is the code piece.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    var isAlarmSet=false
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if let alarmButton = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? BroadcastViewCell{
        var row=indexPath.row
        isAlarmSet = alarmButton.notifyButton.isSelected
        self.alarmButton=alarmButton.notifyButton
        if !isAlarmSet
        {
            //Calculating the date variable for notification time in this section i dont put it in here because it is too long.

                if (date?.timeIntervalSinceNow.sign == .minus)
                {
                    let alertController=UIAlertController(title:"UYARI" , message: "Programın süresi geçmiştir.", preferredStyle: .alert )
                    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Tamam", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

                    }
                    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
                else
                {
                    let alertController=UIAlertController(title:show.programName , message: "Program başlamadan 10 dakika önce uyarı alacaksınız.", preferredStyle: .alert )
                    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "İptal", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

                    }
                    let acceptAction=UIAlertAction(title: "Tamam" , style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

                        if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
                        {
                            let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday, .hour, .minute], from: date!)

                            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: false)

                            //Set the request for the notification from the above
                            let request = UNNotificationRequest(
                                identifier: (show.airDate)!+(show.airTime)!,
                                content: content,
                                trigger: trigger
                            )

                            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
                            { (error:Error?) in
                                if error != nil
                                {
                                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                                    return
                                }
                                print("Notification Register Success")
                                alarmButton.notifyButton.isSelected=true
                                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests
                                {   (requests) in
                                        self.notifications=requests
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
                    alertController.addAction(acceptAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: try to reload data after your event occur

Comment: Do you mean tableView.reloadData()? It doesn't respond either

Comment: Do you try set this property in `DispatchQueue.main.async { alarmButton.notifyButton.isSelected=true }`

Comment: It worked like a charm when i put it inside DispatchQueue.main.async, Thanks a lot for help. @Adrian Bobrowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI can be updated **only** on main thread, then use

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    alarmButton.notifyButton.isSelected=true 
}
```